# After successful signing in, function acquireToken() fails to get a token

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I have an app where I secured azure functions API with Azure AD. I am using simple js/html frontend and adal.js for authentication. The app was working fine but two weeks ago one client reports me an issue that he can't use the API and sees an error message that he doesn't have permissions for the api. 
The problem is quite odd because:

- The app is still working for the rest of the clients
- He can successfully login and use the app from a different computer.
- On the computer where he has a problem he can successfully sign in to the app (I see this in logs in Azure AD app). After logging to app the `acquireToken()` returns an error about timeout. The returned token is then undefined and thus doing the request without a token returns error that he doesn't have permissions for the API.

He was trying to login to app with Firefox and Opera also in incognito mode but still facing the same error.

So my question is do you have any idea why this app stopped working only on one computer?

Comment: Where token is being stored?

Comment: @BilalAhmedYaseen tokens are stored in session storage and the client has a token in storage after login.